# getting exception in oracle query with context to date handling

Tags: oracle

I have the below oracle query which is throwing the exception , below is the query

```
SELECT GFT.*, PA.*,P.* FROM GFT_DATA GFT, CONTACT_TOKEN CT, EDUCT_ATTRIBUTE PA,
PERSON P WHERE GFT.PERSON_ID = 122445220 AND GFT.TO_CONTACT_TOKEN_ID = CT.CONTACT_TOKEN_ID 
AND GFT.EDUCT_ATTRIBUTE_ID = PA.EDUCT_ATTRIBUTE_ID AND GFT.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
AND GFT.CREATED_ON  > CAST ('3-JUN-18 00:00:00' AS DATE) 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <= CAST ('5-JUN-18 23:59:59' AS DATE);
```

Exception which is coming as

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Now please advise me how can i correct this above query so that it brings the data for all the days that is for 3 june ,4 june and
5th june , also i am using cast is it effective or any other better option is there

Answer (score 1):

Casting the date relies on your NLS session parameters, and they don't currently match the format of the string you are providing. As a demo:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';

select CAST ('3-JUN-18 00:00:00' AS DATE) from dual;

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS';

select CAST ('3-JUN-18 00:00:00' AS DATE) from dual;

CAST('3-JUN-1800:0
------------------
03-JUN-18 00:00:00
```

It's better to avoid that issue completely by using the `to_date()` function, which allows you to specify the string format:

```
AND GFT.CREATED_ON  > TO_DATE('3-JUN-18 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <= TO_DATE('5-JUN-18 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
```

I've included the optional third argument to specify the date language because you are using month names. If you can, change the string format to use month numbers, and 4-digit years:

```
AND GFT.CREATED_ON  > TO_DATE('03/06/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <= TO_DATE('05/06/2018 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

It would also generally be better to do your range as:

```
AND GFT.CREATED_ON >= TO_DATE('03/06/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <  TO_DATE('06/06/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

which includes everything from exactly midnight on the 3rd (which your version excludes because of `>`, so you only see things from 00:00:01) and up to, but not including, midnight on the 6th.

That doesn't need the time to be specified really, as it defaults to midnight;, so you could simplify it to:

```
AND GFT.CREATED_ON >= TO_DATE('03/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <  TO_DATE('06/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

and it could be simplified even further with unambiguous date literals:

```
AND GFT.CREATED_ON >= DATE '2018-06-03' 
AND GFT.CREATED_ON <  DATE '2018-06-06';
```

---

Incidentally, you should really start using modern join syntax, and it's usually not a good idea to use `*` - it's better to list out the columns you actually need from each table. For a start, the columns used in the join conditions will be shown twice, one from each of the joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

From question it is not clear on what is the date format of created_at field. Most probably this issue might be because of wrong date format you are comparing.

Below is the useful link for ORA-01830 error.

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01830.php

Comment: In Oracle columns and variables of type "DATE" doesn't have format.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `CAST` with `TO_DATE`:

```
to_date('3-JUN-18 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

I suggest to use [ISO-8601 International date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)  for date strings:

```
to_date('2018-06-03 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```